# Create Apps which have Transaction facilities in android?

Tags: android

I want to know how to implements money transaction type facilities in android ? Please give me some possible suggestion to do it or some example of code ..?

Answer (score 0):

Would in-app billing work for you? http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html